# How to use checkboxes as radio buttons with listners in android

Tags: android

I have 7 check boxes ,On checking one check box other should unchecked

I need multiple check boxes  in `activity`   its functionality works as `radio button` with `listener` get.

Comment: Have you any code, where you are try ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Listview for this

adapter_radio_buttons.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/radios"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Set This adapter to Listview

```
private int selectedPosition = -1;

 private class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

         return 7;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout. , parent, false);
        }
       CheckBox radios = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radios);

        if (selectedPosition == position) {
            radios.setChecked(true);

        } else {
            radios.setChecked(false);
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                radios.performClick();
            }
        });
        radios.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (position == selectedPosition) {
                    selectedPosition = -1;
                    radios.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    radios.setChecked(true);
                    selectedPosition = position;
                }
                vL_apor_reasonsList.invalidateViews();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```